# Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder

Tags: html, font-awesome, placeholder

Is it possible to use Font Awesome Icon in a Placeholder? I read that HTML isn't allowed in a placeholder. Is there a workaround?

```html
placeholder="<i class='icon-search'></i>"
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can't add an icon and text because you can't apply a different font to part of a placeholder, however, if you are satisfied with just an icon then it can work. The FontAwesome icons are just characters with a custom font (you can look at the [FontAwesome Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) for the escaped Unicode character in the `content` rule. In the less source code it's found in [variables.less](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/less/variables.less) The challenge would be to swap the fonts when the input is not empty. Combine it with jQuery like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ADjTF/).

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="iconified" placeholder="&#xF002;"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

With this CSS:

```css
input.empty {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

And this (simple) jQuery

```js
$('#iconified').on('keyup', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if(input.val().length === 0) {
        input.addClass('empty');
    } else {
        input.removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

The transition between fonts will not be smooth, however.

Comment: FontAwesome will show regular characters for all non unicode symbols. For me inserting a unicode entity does not work, but pasting in the symbol works: placeholder=" Hello"

Comment: With FontAwesome 5 use font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free; instead.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz, ```font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;``` doesn't work. I had to use just ```font-family: FontAwesome;```

Comment: Actually you can apply different fonts to the input. I did this on a install with FA5 Pro on it & applied ```font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro', 'Montserrat';``` to the search field & it worked a charm.

Comment: @JeffW it works with FA5 but not with FA6.

Answer (score 269):

If you're using `FontAwesome 4.7` this should be enough:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" />
```

A list of hex codes can be found in the [Font Awesome cheatsheet](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).  However, in the lastest FontAwesome 5.0 this method does not work (even if you use the CSS approach combined with the updated `font-family`).

Comment: This worked the best for me as you can mix icons with regular text like this: `placeholder="&#xF002; Search..."`.

Comment: Clean and clever! But I had to switch the order of the font families in the inline css.

Comment: where did you get `&#xF002;` value? I mean how you go from `icon-search` to `&#xF002`?

Comment: I had to put  `:placeholder => "&#xF002;".html_safe` in my Rails app

Comment: You don't even need the `id="iconified"` just add `class="fa"` and font awesome will take care of the css for you.

Comment: I had to change the font order to make it work: `<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf002; Search Blog" style="font-family: FontAwesome, Arial; font-style: normal">`. Otherwise a symbol containing "fl" was shown.

Comment: @ІгарЦімошка The hex codes are all shown on the cheatsheet https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in React because it escapes HTML characters?

Comment: You sir or ma'am are flippin awesome! I spent quite a while trying to figure this out. I have no idea why this isn't the accepted answer. Upvote!!

Comment: If you have issued with JS escaping the `&` then you can also use `\uf002` in JS and the HMTL entity in the HTML markup.

Comment: I've [got this working in Font Awesome 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576496/163495)

Comment: This helped but my text placeholder also changes to different font.

Comment: Thanks! This trick may also work for other icon fonts. I'm using it with "boxicons".

Answer (score 24):

I solved with this method:

In the CSS I used this code for the **fontAwesome class**:

```
.fontAwesome {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', FontAwesome, sans-serif;
}
```

In the HTML I have added the **fontawesome class** and the **fontawesome icon code** inside the placeholder:

```
<input type="text" class="fontAwesome" name="emailAddress" placeholder="&#xf0e0;  insert email address ..." value="">
```

You can see in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/huckbit/pen/rezezb?editors=1100#0).

Comment: This does also work for FA5 Pro using `input[type="text"]::placeholder {
                            text-align: right;
                            font-family: Roboto, 'Font Awesome\ 5 Pro', sans-serif;
                            font-weight: 600;
                        }    `

Answer (score 20):

@Elli's answer can work in FontAwesome 5, but it requires using the correct font name and using the specific CSS for the version you want.  For example when using FA5 Free, I could not get it to work if I included the all.css, but it worked fine if I included the solid.css:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/solid.css">

<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search" style="font-family: Arial, 'Font Awesome 5 Free'" />
```

For FA5 Pro the font name is 'Font Awesome 5 Pro'

Answer (score 11):

Where supported, you can use the `::input-placeholder` pseudoselector combined with `::before`.

See an example at:

http://codepen.io/JonFabritius/pen/nHeJg

I was just working on this and came across this article, from which I modified this stuff:

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css

Comment: This doesn't quite work in Firefox 27 can you please revisit I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Use `placeholder="&#xF002;"` in your input. You can find unicode in FontAwesome page http://fontawesome.io/icons/ .
But you have to make sure add `style="font-family: FontAwesome;"` in your input.

Answer (score 8):

I am using Ember (version 1.7.1) and I needed to both bind the value of the input and have a placeholder that was a FontAwesome icon. The only way to bind the value in Ember (that I know of) is to use the built in helper. But that causes the placeholder to be escaped, "&#xF002" just shows up just like that, text.

If you are using Ember or not, you need to set the CSS of the input's placeholder to have a font-family of FontAwesome. This is SCSS (using [Bourbon for the placeholder styling](http://bourbon.io/docs/#placeholder)):

```
    input {
      width:96%;
      margin:5px 2%;
      padding:0 8px;
      border:1px solid #444;
      border-radius: 14px;
      background: #fff;
      @include placeholder {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome', $gotham;
      }
    }
```

If you are just using handlebars, as has been mentioned before you can just set the html entity as the placeholder:

```
<input id="listFilter" placeholder="&#xF002;" type="text">
```

If you are using Ember bind the placeholder to a controller property that has the unicode value.

in the template:

```
{{text-field
  id="listFilter"
  placeholder=listFilterPlaceholder
  value=listFilter}}
```

on the controller:

```
listFilter: null,
listFilterPlaceholder: "\uf002"
```

And the value binding works fine!

[image: placeholder example]

[image: placeholder gif]

Comment: This is using Ember 1.7.1

Comment: Nice post for those who are using other web technologies.

Comment: Many thanks! scratching my head for quite a bit. thanks for detailing the solution!

Answer (score 6):

I know this question it is very old. But I didn't see any simple answer like I used to use.

You just need to add the `fas` class to the input and put a **valid hex** in this case `&#xf002` for Font-Awesome's glyph as here `<input type="text" class="fas" placeholder="&#xf002" />`

You can find the unicode of each glyph in [the official web here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/search?style=solid).

This is a simple example you don't need css or javascript.

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="fas" placeholder="&#xf002" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the answer for Font Awesome 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Anyone wondering about a **Font Awesome 5** implementation:

Do not specify a general "Font Awesome 5" font family, you need to specifically end with the branch of icons you're working with. Here I am using the branch "Brands" for example.

```html
<input style="font-family:'Font Awesome 5 Brands' !important" 
       type="text" placeholder="&#xf167">
```

More detail [Use Font Awesome (5) icon in input placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052813)

Answer (score 4):

I do this by adding `fa-placeholder` class to input text:

`<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xF002;" />`

so, in css just add this:

`.fa-placholder {
    font-family: "FontAwesome"; }`

It works well for me.

Update:

To change font while user type in your text input, just add your font after font awesome

`.fa-placholder {
    font-family: "FontAwesome", "Source Sans Pro"; }`

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the jQuery this can be done using `::placeholder` of an input element.

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="&#xF002;"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

The css part

```
input.name::placeholder{ font-family:fontAwesome; font-size:[size needed]; color:[placeholder color needed] }

input.name{ font-family:[font family you want to specify] }
```

THE BEST PART: 
You can have different font family for placeholder and text

Answer (score 2):

If you can / want to use Bootstrap the solution would be input-groups:

```
<div class="input-group">
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
  </div>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="-">
</div>
```

Looks about like this:[input with text-prepend and search symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Sct.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem a bit differently and it works with any FA icon through html code. Instead of all these difficulties with placeholder my solution is:

1. To place an icon in the usual manner

```
HTML
<i class="fas fa-icon block__icon"></i>
<input type="text" name="name" class="block__input" placeholder="Some text">
```

```
CSS
.block__icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin: some-corrections;
}
.block__input {
  padding: some-corrections;
}
```

2. Then adjust placeholder's text (it's personal for everyone, in my case an icon was just before the text)

```
HTML
<!-- For example add some spaces in placeholder, to make focused cursor stay before an icon -->
...placeholder="    Some text"...
```

3. Here is the problem that an icon is above the our input and blocks cursor to click so we should add one more line in our CSS

```
CSS
.block__icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin: some-corrections;

  /* The new line */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

4. But an icon doesn't disappear together with placeholder so we need to fix it. And also this is **the final version** of my solution:

```
HTML
<i class="fas fa-icon block__icon"></i>
<input type="text" name="name" class="block__input" placeholder="    Some text">
```

```
CSS
.block__icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2; /* New line */
  margin: some-corrections;
}
.block__input {
  position: relative; /* New line */
  z-index: 2; /* New line */
  padding: some-corrections;
}
/* New */
.block__input:placeholder-shown {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

It's harder than I thought before, but I hope I've helped anyone with this.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/dzakh/pen/YzKqJvy

Comment: Really like your answer since it's a JS-free solution. Will add my 2 cents here. First of all, be warned about the support here (the pseudo selector is quite new, and won't be supported in any older IE-like browsers).
Secondly, changing z-index frequently might impact performance (and you cannot animate it). Thus, I suggest changing opacity instead. See here: https://codepen.io/matis28/pen/dyOpgob

Answer (score 1):

There is some slight delay and jank as the font changes in the answer provided by Jason. Using the "change" event instead of "keyup" resolves this issue.

```
$('#iconified').on('change', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if(input.val().length === 0) {
        input.addClass('empty');
    } else {
        input.removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I added both text and icon together in a placeholder.

```
placeholder="Edit &nbsp; &#xf040;"
```

CSS :

```
font-family: FontAwesome,'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Teocci [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358852/9918412) is as simple as it can be, thus, no need to add any CSS, just add class="fas" for Font Awesome 5, since it adds proper CSS font declaration to the element.

Here's an example for search box within Bootstrap navbar, with search icon added to the both input-group and placeholder (for the sake of demontration, of course, no one would use both at the same time).
Image:
https://i.imgur.com/v4kQJ77.png ">
Code:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control fas text-right" placeholder="&#xf002;" aria-label="Search string">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-success input-group-text bg-success text-white border-0">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes above all answer not woking, when you can use below trick

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">

<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="iconified" placeholder="search">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Question specifically asked for an icon inside a placeholder, not showing it there always.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="iconified" placeholder="search">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </div>
</form>

.form-group {
  position: relative;
}
i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
}
input {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```