# Font Awesome and Bootstrap 4 Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am looking for an example of using Fontawesome and the Navbar components of Bootstrap  4 so that I have a text description and an icon next to each other.

Answer (score 14):

Well, see [Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration/33768443#33768443) in the first place. You can also simply load Font Awesoms' CSS from CDN:

The links in the navbar are just "normal" anchors (`a`) so you can add the icon inside them:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#">
Features<i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></a>
```

Example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>Navbar</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>
Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
Features<i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-btc"></i>
Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

To add a search icon in the `placeholder` of the search form, see: [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder)

Comment: Thanks! That is the information and example I was looking for.