# Select2 Font Awesome Icon on Placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, jquery-select2

How to add FontAwesome before the placeholder text on Select2.

This is my Select2 option code:

```
var placeholder = "<i class='fa fa-search'></i>  " + "Select a places";
$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: placeholder,
    width: null
});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<select class="form-control select2">
    <option></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with 'before' ?

Comment: Select box has not placeholder property.. so please use first option to placeholder.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean the icon is on the left of the placeholder text.

Comment: @javedrathod, thank you for the comment, but select2 has it.

Comment: i think you want search icon before select 2 right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder this might be helpful. :)

Comment: @javedrathod, yes. but I hope it can be editable so I can change it with different icon someday.

Comment: `<i class='fa fa-search'></i> <select><option>test</option></select>` just like this

Comment: @AjayMakwana, thank you I've been there. unfortunately, like javedrathod said, select box has not placeholder property. that page you refer are for input box.

Comment: @cocksparrer take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare the `escapeMarkup` function between Select2 options, then use "search" icon code (you can find it in the [Font-Awesome Cheatsheet](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) page) for the `placeholder`:

```js
$(function() {
  var placeholder = "&#xf002 Select a place";
  $(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: placeholder,
    width: null,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { 
       return m; 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.select2 {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome'
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Worked successfully. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo that was the case of his question 

Comment: hi @AlessioCantarella, yes. Do you have a way of using a non escaped placeholder in a mmultiple select?

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo create a new question on StackOverflow

Comment: @AlessioCantarella sorry you're right. Here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141438/non-escaped-select2-placeholder-on-multiple-select