# How to prevent Drupal 7 from converting & to &amp;

Tags: drupal, character-encoding, drupal-7

I'm adding placeholder to search form like this:

```
$form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = '&#xf002; Search';
```

But problem is that drupal is printing `&` sign as `&amp;` so in HTML output 
for placeholder attribute instead of:

```
placeholder="&#xf002; Search"
```

I'm getting:

```
placeholder="&amp;#xf002; Search"
```

How to prevent this behavior or is there another way to print that character by it's hex value? Tried using:

`[&#xf002;]` and `decode_entities('&#xf002;')` and some other functions, but none of them helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close with decode_entities(), but you could try the PHP function html_entity_decode().

However, unless the field you are trying to add the place holder to is called 'search_block_form', I think it is your construct which is wrong.

If you are doing this is a hook_form_alter() (which you should be if you are writing it like this) and the field you want to add the placeholder to is called "my_text_field", then the function should look for like this:

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'custom_form') {
    $form['my_text_field']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002; Search');
  }
}
```

Just remember to replace 'custom_form' with the real ID of your form and 'my_text_field' with the name of your field you want to alter.

/**** EDIT ****/

Finally understood what you are trying to do. To get this working on my site I had to lay my form item out like this:

```
$form['test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'placeholder' => html_entity_decode('&#xF002;'),
      'style' => array('font-family: Arial, FontAwesome;'),
    ),
);
```

The important thing to add is the style attribute of font family and make sure it includes FontAwesome.
So the above example for you would become:

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'custom_form') {
    $form['my_text_field']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002; Search');
    $form['my_text_field']['#attributes']['style'] = 'font-family: Arial, FontAwesome;';
  }
}
```

Not sure how you have added the JS for Font Awesome, but I added it in a page alter using drupal_add_js() so that I could make sure it only get loaded on the pages its required.

Let me know how that works out for you, and don't forget the flush your caches too!

Comment: Nope, not working. In page source instead of &#xf002; I'm just getting some empty rectangle character.

Comment: Is this code for a font awesome icon? If so, have you added the javascript for the library?

Comment: Yes it is. And when it's printed hard-coded it works well. But when I add it like I described in my questions drupal converts that & sign to &amp; and it's not working that way.

Comment: BTW I tried adding it with JS and when I inspect it placeholder value is ok, input has "FontAwesome" class but again I see the code instead of icon?! Do I have to do something after setting this with JS (since attribute and css class were not present from start)?

Comment: I've updated my answer as I think i've solved it. Found most of the answer here : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24255639/1578074](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24255639/1578074)

Comment: Yep, that's it!. Heh, I probably tried that function before, but I missed that I have to set up the CSS with style there.