# Is it possible to add icon to the TextInput placeholder at React Native?

Tags: react-native, icons, placeholder, textinput

I have this simple text input with placeholder:

I need to add search icon before placeholder text. 
I need add it exactly in placeholder.

If it possible, please help me with it.

Thank you.

[Search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsjSv.png)

Comment: check [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder)

Comment: Not work for me. React Native.

Comment: Can you describe what you need with the picture ?

Comment: Picture added. Look at Search bar.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use library for that, i use `native-base` library, there are already icon textbox, you can modify for placeholder too, this is the reference :

https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects

please tell me if you want an example, maybe can help you, thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not good for me. I need icon exactly at placeholder. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: let me try it first

Comment: how about this library, i thinks this another way to make an icon in placeholder https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects