# Use Font Awesome (5) icon in input placeholder text

Tags: input, font-awesome, placeholder, font-awesome-5

I've come across many ways to solve this using Font Awesome < 5, but I can't seem to solve this in any way using Font Awesome 5.

This is how many resources point to adding a Font Awesome icon in placeholder text.

```html
<input style="font-family:FontAwesome !important" type="text" placeholder="&#xf167">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember to not use the general "Font Awesome 5" font family, you need to specifically end with the branch of icons you're working with. Here i am working the "Brands" category.

```html
<input style="font-family:'Font Awesome 5 Brands' !important" type="text" placeholder="&#xf167">
```

For a more sophisticated solution you could implement a class that works specifically on the placeholder text of a class like this and add that class to you input. Useful if you want a different font-family on your input values.

```css
.useFontAwesomeFamily::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands" !important;
}
.useFontAwesomeFamily:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands" !important;
}
.useFontAwesomeFamily::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands" !important;
}
.useFontAwesomeFamily:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands" !important;
}
.useFontAwesomeFamily::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands" !important;
}
.useFontAwesomeFamily::placeholder { /* Most modern browsers */
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands" !important;
}
```

And then add this class to your tag.

```html
<input class="useFontAwesomeFamily" type="text" placeholder="&#xf167;">
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help someone out there as I had the same issue.

The Branch for Regular icons is **Font Awesome 5 Free**. However, if you need to use solid icons, just add the **font-weight: 900;** property to the inline CSS.

```
<style="font-family: Circular, 'Font Awesome 5 Free' !important; font-weight: 900;">
```

The placeholder text will be bold, I'm still trying to find a solution for this, I don't know if there's another way but it works for me for now.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also the fas class to the input.

Just bear in mind that this solution and any font-awesome style changing solutions will also change the style of any text preceding or following the unicode icon.

Comment: Please post example with it

Comment: @saAction `<input class="fas fa-search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="&#xf002; Search...">`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add class "fas fa-search" to the input