# set fontawesome icon to a placeholder

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I tried differents solutions found here but nothing works. What I need is to set the fontawesome f14a to a field
what's wrong ?

```
document.getElementById('property_charges').setAttribute('class', 'fontawesome-placeholder');
document.getElementById('property_charges').placeholder = '&#f14a';
```

and the css:

```
.fontawesome-placeholder {
  //padding:10px;
  //font-family: FontAwesome;
  //z-index: 9999;
  //z-index: 1;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
}
```

the suggested solution on the "duplicate" doesn't work + I don't want Jquery on my project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder)

Comment: _“the suggested solution doesn't work”_ - which one? You got one possible duplicate referred to by now, and two answers already … and now we are supposed to know what you mean by that? Please be a little more specific. If the answers don’t work as you want, then comment under them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using JS/jQ and unicode, a `u` must be added after the forward slash. Do not use the HTML entity unless you intend to place it directly into HTML. There are some required CSS styles as well.

```js
document.getElementById('fa').setAttribute('placeholder', '\uf14a');
```

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input id='fa' class='icon'>
```

Comment: nice thank you !
by any chance, are you using symfony/webpack-encore ? cause it's breaking the "default style"

Comment: You're welcome, no not using anything but what's in the demo. Try removing the styles in `.icon` class with the exception of `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"` Also this is FA5 make sure that you are using the correct version. If you are using FA4 this will still work by changing `font-family` to `FontAwesome`.

Comment: for information: when I was using setAttribute('class', 'blabla'), I was deleting the default class used in Symfony fields, use .classList.add('new-class') instead

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your goal is to use Font Awesome for a placeholder and revert the font when the user enters a value, you don't need JavaScript for that. This can be done solely with CSS by using [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder).

(Note that you're missing an "x": `&#f14a --> &#xf14a;`)

```css
#property_charges::placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<input id="property_charges" placeholder="&#xf14a;">
```

<sup>(In my example, my font name has to be `"Font Awesome 5 Free"` because I'm using Font Awesome 5. If you're using an older version, your font will likely remain `FontAwesome`.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('fa').setAttribute('placeholder', '\uf14a');
```

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input id='fa' class='icon'>
```