# How do insert the email envelop icon inside the placeholder box?

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

How do insert the email envelop icon inside the placeholder box,in the form nested under div which is again nested under a section. Below is my code:
HTML code:

```html
<section id="newsletter">
<div class="container">
<h2>Subscribe To Our Newsletter.</h2>
<form>
<i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i> 
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email....">
<button type="submit" class="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
</form>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS code:

```css
#newsletter.container i { 
padding: 5px; 
min-width: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

On placeholder="xxxxxx; Enter email...." ,replace xxxxxx with & #xf0e0; where f0e0 is envelope's unicode. You can find unicode in FontAwesome page http://fontawesome.io/icons/ .

```
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf0e0; Enter email...." style="font-family: FontAwesome, Arial; font-style: normal">
```

Comment: Yes it worked. However if I want to take the style under my CSS file?