# How to use open-iconic-bootstrap in placeholder of a input

Tags: html, css, icons

https://useiconic.com/open

I want to use a icon in placeholder

`<input type="text" placeholder="xxx" />`

In bootstrap icon I can use `&#xf002` But in this icon I can not find the icon code.

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the code of the icon by checking the .css file of the font.
If the icon you're are searching for is written like this

```
.oi[data-glyph=caret-right]:before { content:'\e02f'; }
```

Then the unicode in HTML will be written like this `&#xe02f`.

https://codepen.io/mlarabi/pen/QWpXNBR

In this example I used the CDN of Open Iconic (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic.min.css) and changed the `font-family` of the `placeholder` of the `input` to use the `Icons` font given by the CSS.

Comment: how to change the position of the icon it is not center with the placeholder text

Comment: This depends on the font mainly. I updated my CodePen with another font (FontAwesome) to show you that. If you really want to style the icon you should use SVg directly (like in @swhite solution below).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/solid.css">

<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search" style="font-family: Arial, 'Font Awesome 5 Free'" />
```