# How do I use an HTML inline tag inside a string?

Tags: html

I have an `svg` icon (which is the symbol of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key):

```
<kbd class="DocSearch-Commands-Key">
    <svg width="15" height="15" aria-label="Enter key" role="img">
        <g fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.2">
            <path d="M12 3.53088v3c0 1-1 2-2 2H4M7 11.53088l-3-3 3-3"></path>
       </g>
   </svg>
</kbd>
```

I have an `input` text field like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Press the ENTER key">
```

I want to append the `svg` icon inside the `placeholder` of the input field, such that the `placeholder` is like

> Press the <kbd><-|</kbd> key

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT:** The button icons should be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kz4T.png)

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder)

Comment: I want the `icon` to have a button like shape, so that it looks like the `Enter` key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `placeholder` property since it only supports text.

If your icon can be a font icon, you could do it as [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder).

There's a workaround that you could fake a placeholder using `:placeholder-shown` pseudo class, so the *"placeholder"* can be anything.

For example:

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper .placeholder {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.input-wrapper input:placeholder-shown + .placeholder {
  display: flex;
}

/* customization */
input {
  padding: 6px;
}

.DocSearch-Commands-Key {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 4px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder=" ">
  <span class="placeholder">
    Press the
    <kbd class="DocSearch-Commands-Key">
      <svg width="15" height="15" aria-label="Enter key" role="img">
        <g fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.2">
            <path d="M12 3.53088v3c0 1-1 2-2 2H4M7 11.53088l-3-3 3-3"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </kbd>
     key
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The button like shape is not showing around the icon. It just looks like a normal icon.

Comment: There, I customized it for you, for the `<kbd>` details, you could do it whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert your SVG to URI to use as a background.
I used the following site to convert the SVG to URI
[SVG to CSS background-image converter](https://websemantics.uk/tools/svg-to-background-image-conversion/)
Then you need to adjust the width of your input field to show it in the centre of the text.
You can also adjust the width of the SVG to adjust it between words.

```js
function myFunction()
{
  let input = document.getElementById('input')
  if(input.value.length>0)
    {
    input.style.background = 'none'
    }
  else{
    input.style.background = `url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='15' height='15' aria-label='Enter key' role='img'%3E%3Cg fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='1.2'%3E%3Cpath d='M12 3.53088v3c0 1-1 2-2 2H4M7 11.53088l-3-3 3-3'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E")center / contain no-repeat`;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='15' height='15' aria-label='Enter key' role='img'%3E%3Cg fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='1.2'%3E%3Cpath d='M12 3.53088v3c0 1-1 2-2 2H4M7 11.53088l-3-3 3-3'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E")center / contain no-repeat;
background-origin:border-box;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Press the           Key" id='input' oninput="myFunction();"/>
</label>
```